# How to connect these faces smoothly (if possible)

Tags: faces, displacement

I want to make a cliff scene like this in Blender: 
[image]

So in order to do that, I'm trying to connect these two faces together (each one is a plane and has a displace and a subdivision surface modifier) [image]

However, when I connect the two faces in Edit Mode, it looks like this:
[image]

What should I do? Should I even connect the faces at all?

Comment: Have you tried the bridge edge loops command in edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't have connected them in edit mode. First off, select any one of the plane in object mode. Then add the boolean modifier to it. Select the second plane as boolean object and set the type to union.

Alternatively, you can try sculpting your mesh with smooth brush.

Comment: I tried the boolean step, and nothing happened, so I applied it and my computer froze. Sculpting only lets you edit the mesh and not apply anything new (I think).

Comment: I've added another answer. Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

This could work, select both of your mesh object, and join them, and then you can click the edges, and then from the menu:  Edge > bridge edge loops.

Answer (score -1):

This might probably help. 
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]
Let me know if this works for you.